# php curl - Accessing iframe src with the same cookies

Tags: php, curl

here I am having this problem :

I'm accessing a page let's say "http://my-page.com", it;s uses authentication, I pass the auth. so all is ok, but the page has an iframe and the iframe source is accessible only when the main's page auth is passed, so, when after the auth I am trying to access the iframe's src as a separate page then it fails and it says that I am not logged in. Here is the sample of the code :

```
   public $curl;
   public $url = "http://my-page.com/";
   public $loginName = "loginName";
   public $loginPassword = "pwdkjojdf";

    public function requstIframe() {
        $r = [
            '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
            '__VIEWSTATE' => '/wEPDwULLTExNDk5OTk1NTAPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgQCAQ88KwANAQAPFgIeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2RkAgQPDxYCHgRUZXh0BRAoU2VydmVkIGJ5IHd3dzEpZGRkfTiA/PvIVryBc6c20gH5cnLW0Ec=', //'/wEPDwULLTExNDk5OTk1NTAPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgQCAQ88KwANAQAPFgIeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2RkAgQPDxYCHgRUZXh0BRAoU2VydmVkIGJ5IHd3dzEpZGRkfTiA/PvIVryBc6c20gH5cnLW0Ec=',
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => 'CA0B0334',
            '__PREVIOUSPAGE' => '1Cn2CuxagyuY2V7hXmPg2NQ6W2Ov92BIEUHfsC5ZCJeAgWcgn5yoZLzxlVfS568UGx9I2Tf3gSiSmfNeiz-PxfjLSFQ1',
            '__LASTFOCUS' => '',
            'ctl00$LoginView1$Login1$UserName' => $this->loginName,
            'ctl00$LoginView1$Login1$Password' => $this->loginPassword,
            'ctl00$LoginView1$Login1$LoginButton' => 'Enter',
            'aspnetForm' => ''
        ];

        $r = http_build_query($r);

        $this->curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $r);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/tmp.txt');  
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/tmp.txt'); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        curl_exec($this->curl);

        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.iframe-source-url.com/');

        $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
    }
```

do you have any idea why it can be like this?

Comment: 1) Can you write to `__DIR__.'/tmp.txt'`? 2) Do you have one Cookie-file for all users? 3) Do you need do pass any initial cookies?

Comment: Yes, I can write to "__DIR__.'/tmp.txt'"
Yes, I have one cookie file for all users
No initial cookies are required to be passed

Comment: Okay, I saw that I am not passing ASPXAUTH to the frame src, but when accessing main page it is there, that is why this cannot open it with the same access data - probably

Comment: anyways it didn't help, I set the .ASPXAUTH manually, I load the stored cookie file, but anyway it doesn't work as it's supposed to

Answer (score 0):

After the first `curl_exec($this->curl);` close your `$curl` handle. And then reinitialize it again with all the same parameters. After that call the Iframe link. If you do not close curl handle, it will not run anything to the cookie file.

```
curl_close($this->curl);
$this->curl = curl_init();
... set other params here! again
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.iframe-source-url.com/');
```

As you are using verbose mode, I believe you can see that no cookie is sent during your second curl request, but from you first response you have seen some `Set-Cookie` in http response header.

Comment: I re-initialized the way you said, but anyway the problem is still the same

Comment: also, in the developer tools > resources > cookies I noticed that there are two cookie storages they are from the main web site and from the iframe source, but when I save the cookies to the file there are cookies only from the main web but not from the iframe source, and that's why it always fails. so any ideas how to fix that cookie file the way to store all the cookies but not only from the main source